# How to convert an integer into an array of digits

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an integer, say `12345`, to an array like `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

I have tried the below code, but is there a better way to do this?

```
var n = 12345;
var arr = n.toString().split('');
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = +arr[i] | 0;
```

Comment: A simpler way would be `.map(Number)` or `.map(parseInt)`, but that doesn't cast `NaN` to `0` as your bitwise operation does.

Comment: Why do you need the `|0`?

Comment: @Bergi `.map(Number)` is also not supported in IE8.

Comment: Actually, your code is fine as it is the [fastest of all proposed solutions](http://jsperf.com/extracting-digits-from-a-number)…

Comment: @Bergi.. yeah.. map function is slow ._.

Comment: Questions about code review/code improvements should be asked on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'd go with

```
var arr = n.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
```

You can omit the `replace` if you are sure that `n` has no decimals.

Comment: Mapping with the `Number` function. This is smart :-)

Comment: Mind explaining the .map(Number)? The Number part

Comment: @PaulKruger The [`Number` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) converts a string to a number

Comment: @Bergi Ah I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 122):

## **** *2019 Answer* ****

This single line will do the trick:

```
Array.from(String(12345), Number);
```

### Example

```js
const numToSeparate = 12345;

const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(numToSeparate), Number);

console.log(arrayOfDigits);   //[1,2,3,4,5]
```

### Explanation

1- `String(numToSeparate)` will convert the number 12345 into a string, returning '12345'

2- The `Array.from()` method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object, the string '12345' is an iterable object, so it will create an Array from it.

3- In the process of creating this new array, the `Array.from()` method will first pass any iterable element (ex: '1', '2')  to the callback we declare as a second parameter (which is the `Number` function in this case). This is possible because an String is an "array-like" object.
To make it simpler, we could've declared the callback as:
`Array.from(String(numToSeparate), n => Number(n)`

4- The `Number` function will take any string character and will convert it into a number eg: `Number('1')`; will return `1`.

5- These numbers will be added one by one to a new array and finally this array of numbers will be returned.

**Summary**

The code line `Array.from(String(numToSeparate), Number);` will convert the number into a string, take each character of that string, convert it into a number and put in a new array. Finally, this new array of numbers will be returned.

Comment: Please, an explanation would be appreciable.  Thank you

Comment: @shashiverma please let me know if the added explanation is clear enough ;)

Comment: Thanks juanma, well explained I am a beginner  to this universe so didn't know about this function, You really have good knowledge about js, you're a pro man.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!

Answer (score 12):

I'd do this, to avoid using strings when you don't need them:

```
var n = 12345;
var arr = [];
while(n>0){arr.unshift(n%10);n=n/10|0;}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var n = 12345;
var arr = ('' + n).split('').map(function(digit)  {return +digit;});
```

The map function, though, is only supported by recent browsers.

Comment: I guess it would be relevant to say that `map` function is not supported in MSIE8-

Comment: Well, IE8 definitely doesn't count as a recent browser.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: [Shimming it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) is not hard.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is by using literals and then spread:

```js
const n = 12345;
const arr = [...`${n}`].map(Number);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

date: 24/07/2021

## Using ES6 methods #2021

> input = 12345

> output = [1,2,3,4,5]

```js
const input = 12345;
console.log(`${input}`.split('').map(Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Map(Number). Below code snip can helpful.

```js
 var num = 1230945;
 var result=num.toString().split('').map(Number);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Without to string solution.

This method is **faster** than method with toString transform. Approximately 3-4 times. You can see benchmarks [here](https://jsben.ch/vIj8R) or on screen below.

[image]

```js
const numberToArray = (number) => {
    var arr = [];
    while(number>0) { arr.push(number%10); number = number/10|0; }
    return arr.reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not too late to the party, but...

If you are code golfing, then do

```js
const n = 9876
const a = [...""+n].map(n=>+n) // 20 chars
console.log(a)
```

Explanation:

- `""+` converts `n` into a string to concatenate it with the `""` part
- `...` is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It expands the string `""+n` into an array
- the `+` before `n` in map just converts back every array element from string to number

The rest should be clear. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have fist convert the number to a string and then used Array.from() to convert the string to an array.

```
let dataArray = Array.from(value.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Runnable snippet:

```js
const n = 12345;
let toIntArray = (n) => ([...n + ""].map(Number));
console.log(toIntArray(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the integer is converted string & then to array. Using map function,
individual strings are converted to numbers with the help of parseInt function.
Finally, that array is returned as the result.

```
const digitize = n => [...`${n}`].map(i => parseInt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed work fine in most cases but not with negative numbers.

There is a solution for such cases.

```js
const intToArray = (int) => {
  return String(int).match(/-?\d/g).map(Number)
}

console.log(intToArray(312)) // [3, 1, 2]
console.log(intToArray(-312)) // [-3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the String() method.
It coverts to string but you can use them in term of digits.

But if you want the data as array of string

```js
let val = 1458;
let numbers = String(val);
console.log("First response => ",numbers);
let fromNumberToArray = [...val.toString()].map(Number);
console.log("Second response => ",fromNumberToArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt JS methods toString() and parseInt() as:

```
function toDigitsArr(num) {
  num = num.toString();
  let numArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    numArr[i] = parseInt(num[i]);
  }
  return numArr;
}
console.log(toDigitsArr(9119));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
let n = 12345;
let arr = (""+n).split('');//HERE IS THE ARRAY
///Now for, for loop, you can do something like this
arr.map(element=>{
//Do Something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys are awesome, so many ways to do the trick. Let me put this one into consideration. Please provide feedback if there is something wrong with this approach.

```js
    let fromNumberToArray = [...num.toString()].map(Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way using basic javascript that makes sense:

```
function toNumArray(num) {
     num = num.toString();
      let numArr = []
      for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        numArr.push(num[i])
      }
      return numArr;
    }
 console.log(toNumArray(911956789874))
```

Comment: This is Going to Return an Array of Char you also have to convert it into a number while looping.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the case where the number is negative

```js
function toArr2(num) {
  var myArr = String(Math.abs(num)).split("").map((num)=>{
  return Number(num)})

  if (num <0) myArr[0]*=-1;
  
return myArr;
}

console.log(toArr2(123));
console.log(toArr2(-123));
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Comment: @starball 
we should be aware about how js interpret "-" when we use toString and split. when we map it to Number, we will have Nan in the array, after that you can solve this problem by merging "-" with the first number like i did :
i do the same logic mentionned in the existing answer but if i receive negative number i use abs to eliminate the "-" and in the end i check if the input is negative  or note and write some interpretation in this case .

Answer (score 0):

var n = 12345;

var s = String(n).split('').map(Number);

console.log(s);

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954391/2227743).

Comment: right just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scenario, you might wish to only wrap it with bracelets:
`[myNumber]`

E.g:

```
const myNumber = element.Id;
methodThatReceivesAnArray([myNumber]);
```

Answer (score -3):

This will do the trick.

```
let n = 1234;
console.log(n.toString().split(''));
```