# How can I create an array from each number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an integer and want to create an array from each of its numbers.

```
let interget = 345;
//I want create the array [3,4,5]
```

Is there any easy way to do this using Array.from() or would I need to convert the number to a string first?

Comment: Try this `interget .toString().split('').map(e => parseInt(e))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an integer into an array of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182266/how-to-convert-an-integer-into-an-array-of-digits)

Comment: @visibleman Yes. I was forgetting to add the word digit to my google search. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

easy way by converting to string

```
(inputNumber + "").split("").map(char => +char)
```

basically we split string and convert each character back to number

---

doing it manually

```
function getDigits(n) {
  const ans = [];
  while(n > 0){
    let digit = n % 10;
    ans.push(digit);
    n -= digit;
    n /= 10;
  }

  return ans.reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it like this:

```js
var result = Array.from('345', Number)
console.log(result);
```